# Ruby on Rails Time.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble working with Time.now. For some reason when I save an object to the DB it saves it for the year 2000. I'm trying to make a comparison to the object I saved in the DB to Time.now to check if it is greater, but it always returns false because of the year 2000. Does anyone know of a way I can work around this?

I just need to check to make sure 10 minutes has passed since I created a time object compared to Time.now

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your database column is of type `time` rather than `datetime` or `timestamp`. This will only store the time and when it is converted to a `Time` instance in ruby (which does support day, month, year, etc) the default values are used for day, month, year which is why you're seeing the year 2000.

You probably need to update your database column to be `datetime` or `timestamp` if that is the problem as it sounds like you'll want the day, month, year parts of the time anyway. In which case you're comparisons will work.

Comment: yes, the column is of the type time. I've been trying the created_at part and it still doesn't work..

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I didn't mention created_at.

Comment: yup, I changed it to datetime and it seems to work with u.online.last_seen > 10.minutes.ago

Answer (score 0):

`created_at < 10.minutes.ago` should work

Comment: that doesn't seem to work.. If I just create the object and type 1 minute ago after 2 it still says true

Comment: try appending to_date and see it that helps `created_at < 10.minutes.ago.to_date`

Comment: Is your database server on the same machine as the running code?

Comment: so there is probably a mismatch on your date settings. try to fix that

Comment: what time do you get if you print `created_at` from a newly created object? and what time do you have on your machine?

Comment: created_at is Fri, 10 Sep 2010 06:26:22 UTC +00:00

Comment: my machine is todays date at 3:26

Comment: this seems to work.. u.online.created_at > u.online.create_at - 10.minutes

Comment: but that will always be true.

Comment: your problem, I think, is that your database is in another timezone. you need to compensate for that `u.online.created_at > 3.hours.from_now - 10.minutes` or something similar. experiment with plus and minus and ago/from_now. I have problems thinking about time.

Comment: actually, check your config (in rails3 config/application.rb), there you can set the timezone of your app which will automatically compensate for you.