# Rails virtual attributes error. Syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end self.send(field_name) =

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `start_time:timestamps` and `finish_time:timestamps` fields in `events` table. So I want to store here only hours and minutes.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.time_select :start_time_string %>
```

I added virtual attributes to my model.

**event.rb**

```
  # Generates methods: start_time_string, finish_time_string
  #
  [:start_time, :finish_time].each do |field_name|
    define_method("#{field_name}_string") do
      self.send(field_name).strftime('%H:%M') if self.send(field_name)
    end
  end

  [:start_time, :finish_time].each do |field_name|
    define_method("#{field_name}_string=") do |time|
      self.send(field_name) = time.strftime('%H:%M')
    end
  end
```

But I got error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end self.send(field_name) = time.strftime('%H:%M') ^
```

Why this is happening? Could you please propose a better solution for me if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
[:start_time, :finish_time].each do |field_name|
    define_method("#{field_name}_string=") do |time|
      self.send(field_name) = time.strftime('%H:%M')
    end
  end
```

with

```
[:start_time, :finish_time].each do |field_name|
    define_method("#{field_name}_string=") do |time|
      self.send("#{field_name}_string=",time.strftime('%H:%M'))
    end
end
```

**EDIT**

This will create two methods `start_time_string=` and `finish_time_string=`.

You can call these as,

```
start_time_string = Time.now
finish_time_string = Time.now
```

Comment: Oopps!! let's see OP's reaction.

Comment: You beat me with the answer but I was watching.:)

Comment: You carry on.. I am going.. feel sleepy. :)

Comment: It doesn't work... 
`1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [2014, 3, 5, 22, 45] to start_time_string (undefined method 'klass' for nil:NilClass)]`

Answer (score 1):

@Kirti's answer is correct.

However your error lies in another the fact that your `time_select` field is not a `Time` field in your database.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711948/multiparameter-error-with-datetime-select), there are many suggested solutions.

Comment: A little bit earlier I setted `time` type for my `start_time:time` column.

But after that not only time was stored in database but year, month, day too. So I found same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682991/ruby-on-rails-time-now. 
One of the suggestions is to change column type to `timestamps`.

Comment: Yes, use `:datetime` or `:timestamp`.